# How to get fieldName when inputfield updated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, onchange, lightning-recordeditform

I'm using lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField.
I know that `event.getParam('change')` return updated value.
but I want to get fieldName of inputField which is updated.

thank you.

```
        <lightning:recordEditForm
            recordId="a00R0000000jq5eIAA"
            objectApiName="Bad_Guy__c">

            <lightning:inputField  aura:id="sameId" fieldName="Name" onchange="{!c.change}"/>
            <lightning:inputField  aura:id="sameId" fieldName="Has_Weakness__c" onchange="{!c.change}"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** : `event.getSource().get("v.fieldName")` or `component.find("auraId").get("v.fieldName")`

If you want to fetch `fieldName` based on `aura:id` then `component.find` would return an array, where you can use

```
change : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.find("sameId")[0].get("v.fieldName"))  //Name
    console.log(component.find("sameId")[1].get("v.fieldName"))  //Has_Weakness__c
}
```

But the best way would be using `event.getSource()` as it provides exact `fieldName` based on input field

```
change : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(event.getSource().get("v.fieldName"))
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for ! Thank you very much.